# Laravel query builder returning NULL results when they are clearly in the DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Query:

```
$posts = $this->post->with('games', 'console')->take($limit)->get();
```

So actually dumping the $post I am seeing this on my 4th entry... it is returning NULL

```
["relations":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["games"]=>
    NULL
```

The first 3 return values. But then the 4th on are all returning NULL's. Again i have only 3 values in the Games table

```
Games Table:
1 | game 1
2 | game 2
3 | game 3
```

And actually on the third entry it it has a value of 2 but showing game 3 name

```
posts table: 
id | game id
1 | 3
2 | 2
3 | 3 (but showing "game 1" text)
4 | 3 (anything from 4 on returns NULL)
```

Relationships:

```
Game
public function Post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'game_id');
}

Post
public function console()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Console', 'id');
}

public function games()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Game', 'id');
}

Console
public function Post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'console_id');
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens in my console returns. It uses up all the values from my console table and then returns NULLs ... what in the F :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Post

public function games()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Game', 'id', 'game_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Post` class you are using the relationship to `games` wrong.

First of all, it should be called `game` singular because the `Post` belongs just to one `Game`. However, it can work in plural.

Then, the real problem is you are declaring the relationship like this:

```
public function games()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Game', 'id');
}
```

This is telling Laravel that the `Post` is related to a game with the column `id`, so for example, the record : `{id : 1, game_id : 3}` will be related with the `Game` with `id` 1, and it should be related with the `Game` with id 3. The second argument of the `belongsTo` method is the local column. The 3rd argument is the `id` on the parent column. But it is `id` by default, so you shouldn't be using any of them.

```
public function games()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Game');
}
```

You have the same problem in `console`

Hope it helps.

Comment: i did update that to the following: return $this->hasOne('App\Game', 'id', 'game_id');  that way there is no confusion.